# Private class variable declaration

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying declare a private class variable for a super class and I seem to have trouble doing so. I there something I am missing? This is my code so far.

```js
class Animal {
  constructor(_name) {
      this._name = _name;
  }
  name() {
    console.log(`${this._name} is my name.`);
  }
}

new Animal('Bob').name();
```

Comment: Private fields in js classes start with `#`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_With_Private_Class_Features

Comment: What's the problem with the code you have?

Comment: @FelixKling I'm not sure but my moderator says that I am missing something on the first 3 lines

Answer (score 2):

Private fields start with # but their scope will keep them hidden from subclasses.

```
class Animal {
  #name
  constructor(name) {
      this.#name = name;
  }
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields

Answer (score 0):

[Private class features](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields) are available in the following browsers:

| Chrome | Edge | FireFox | Opera | Safari |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 74+ | 79+ | 90+ | 62+ | 14.1+ |

Here is an example of your class with a private instance field called `name`:

```js
class Animal {
  #name;

  constructor(name) {
      this.#name = name;
  }

  get name() {
    return this.#name;
  }

  toString() {
    return `${this.#name} is my name.`;
  }
}

const bob = new Animal('Bob');

console.log(bob.name);
console.log(bob.toString());

// console.log(bob.#name); <-- SyntaxError
```